How do i make a pause-function work in my WinForms game?
I'm doing a game in C# using WindowsForms which is like Flappy Bird one, but there is a flying mouse instead of a bird. I need to implement a pause function there. I wrote a code which supposed to work right, according to the game logic. But it doesn't work at all and i don't understand why.
First of all i made a "Label" object using WinForms elements, then i wrote a text on it, set  a font and a size, put a white frame below it. In "Visibility" i chose "False".
After that i wrote a code, here it is:
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Flappy_Mouse
{
    public partial class Form2 : Form
    {

        int mouse_speed2 = 3;
        int gravity2 = 5;
        int score2 = 0;

        bool isPaused = false;

        public Form2()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.Size = new Size(600, 650);

            this.KeyPreview = true;
            this.KeyDown += key_is_down2;
            this.KeyUp += key_is_up2;

            this.game_timer2.Tick += new EventHandler(this.game_timer_event2);
            game_timer2.Start();

            this.Controls.Add(pause_taken);
        }

        private void end_game()
        {
            game_timer2.Stop();
        }

        private void game_timer_event2(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            mouse2.Top += gravity2;
            pipe_bottom2.Left -= mouse_speed2;
            pipe_top2.Left -= mouse_speed2;
            score_tab2.Text = "Score: " + score2;

            if (pipe_bottom2.Left < -150)
            {
                pipe_bottom2.Left = 1150;
                score2++;
            }

            if (pipe_top2.Left < -180)
            {
                pipe_top2.Left = 1200;
                score2++;
            }

            if (mouse2.Bounds.IntersectsWith(pipe_bottom2.Bounds) ||
                mouse2.Bounds.IntersectsWith(pipe_top2.Bounds) ||
                mouse2.Bounds.IntersectsWith(ground2.Bounds) ||
                mouse2.Top < -25)
            {
                end_game();
            }

            if (score2 > 10)
            {
                mouse_speed2 = 6;
            }
        }

        private void key_is_down2(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Space)
            {
                gravity2 = -5;
            }

            if (e.KeyCode == Keys.P) 
            {
                TogglePause();
            } 
        }

        private void key_is_up2(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Space)
            {
                gravity2 = 5;
            }
        }


        private void TogglePause()
        {
            if (isPaused == true)
            {
                game_timer2.Start(); 
                isPaused = false;
                pause_taken.Visible = false;
            }
            else
            {
                game_timer2.Stop(); 
                isPaused = true;
                pause_taken.Visible = true;
            }
        }
    }
}

You take a pause by pressing "P" on the keyboard:
            if (e.KeyCode == Keys.P) 
            {
                TogglePause();
            } 

And it addresses to a function where the pause gets either on or off:
        private void TogglePause()
        {
            if (isPaused == true)
            {
                game_timer2.Start(); 
                isPaused = false;
                pause_taken.Visible = false;
            }
            else
            {
                game_timer2.Stop(); 
                isPaused = true;
                pause_taken.Visible = true;
            }
        }

It supposed to work like this: if you press P and bool isPaused = true, then pause is off. If you press P and bool isPaused = false, then the pause is on. But it doesn't work at all. The pause doesn't work and the frame with "Pause" text doesn't show up.
Maybe i messed up with a logic, i'm so lost. Please say me what i'm doing wrong here

did you debug it already? set breakpoints in the keyboard event handlers and look what's going on

@CeeMcSharpface just did it and found my mistake. key_is_down was working two times because at first i set it in winforms and then also in code. i probably completely forgot about it. now everything is working!

You can simply check if (isPaused). Also, you can set pause_taken.Visible = isPaused; after the if-else in a single statement.
